# Create keyboard shortcut in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I tried to create shortcut for restart Task and run Task but it does not work in Visual Studio Code.

My setting in tasks.json and in keybindings.json are like this:

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "Run Python",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "python",
        "args": ["-i", "${file}"]
    },
]}
```

This is keybindings.json:

```
[
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+l",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.restartTask",
    "args": "Run Python"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+k",
    "command": "workbench.action.tasks.runTask",
    "args": "Run Python"
}]
```

Any help how to correct this code?

Comment: which command is executed when you press the shortcut, use the keyboard debugging, see key binding doc page